# How to share directory over NFS from Mac? (w/o macOS Server app)

Tags: macos, unix, server.app, file-sharing, nfs

First of all, I'm happy to pay the $19.99 for the Mac OS Server app from the app store, so that's no problem, it's just that at the moment I only have one specific need - NFS sharing between my macOS sierra host and a virtualbox VM guest running Debian Sarge (don't ask).

This is something I am used to doing in Linux without any difficulty, but the syntax for `/etc/exports` doesn't seem to be the same? In the man page for exports on macOS it uses explicit flags?

My regular line in `/etc/exports` on Linux:

```
# NFS Share to Virtualbox guests:
/path/to/my/shared/directory 192.168.56.0/24(rw,fsid=root,all_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000,no_subtree_check)
```

Calling `nfsd checkexports` returns the following:

```
getaddrinfo() failed for 192.168.56.0/24(rw,fsid=root,all_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000,no_subtree_check)
exports:2: couldn't get address for host: 192.168.56.0/24(rw,fsid=root,all_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000,no_subtree_check)
exports:2: no valid hosts found for export
```

And if I simplify and change the `etc/exports` entry to `/path/to/my/shared/directory -network 192.168.56.0 -mask 255.255.255.0` I get the following output from `nfsd checkexports`:

```
exports:2: path contains non-directory or non-existent components: /path/to/my/shared/directory
exports:2: no usable directories in export entry and no fallback
```

*Note: `/path/to/my/shared/directory` is obviously a just a placeholder filepath for this question, not my actual entry in `/etc/exports`*

Is it just because the line in `/etc/exports` is crap, or I need some other configuration? <s>or do I need the macOS Server app?</s>

From looking at https://help.apple.com/serverapp/mac/5.3/#/apd106E5632-C4E6-4572-8289-B9ACC652E88C it seems like it might not be anything I need the macOS Server app for?

EDIT:

What I want is the equivalent behaviour and rw permissions of `rw,fsid=root,all_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000,no_subtree_check` in my exporting, I've got it working with NFS Manager where I can mount the folder on my VM guest but read-only.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What was required was the following line in `/etc/exports`:

```
/path/to/shared/dir -mapall=<uid of local user on host machine with correct perms> -network 192.168.56.0 -mask 255.255.255.0
```

`exports(5)` is the FreeBSD version, obviously. Once I did some googling for the solution with respect to "FreeBSD" instead of "Mac", the necessary information presented itself, the a colleague pointed out the exact flag needed.

Source: http://www.freebsdmadeeasy.com/tutorials/freebsd/using-freebsd-nfs.php

NFS Manager was helpful in validating the solution but not necessary.

Comment: NFS Manager will also cost you, $20 !

Answer (score 10):

macOS Server is not required at all to share directories over NFS. The macOS client provides all necessary tools.

Testing various exports with bogus paths, I'd assume your path simply doesn't exist.

The most convenient GUI-tool for NFS is [NFS Manager](https://www.bresink.com/osx/NFSManager.html). You will be presented with a nag-screen launching it or changing configurations, but it works without further restrictions.

---

Most of your desired options are available in macOS (check `man exports`) and can be configured with NFS Manager:

[image: NFS Manager screenshot]

Some details have to be configured in the advanced options (e.g. the access permissions).

Comment: The path most definitely does exist 

Comment: I will check out NFS Manager though, and thanks for verifying that I don't need to buy the server app

Comment: @BenjaminR I got said error only when I entered non-existent paths in /etc/exports (which doesn't happen with NFS Manager, because it offers a file system browser). Haven't tested it with aliases or soft links though.

Comment: NB NFS Manager will cost $20