# How to mount nfs drive on macOS with read+write access?

Tags: terminal, command-line, mount, nfs

I'm trying to mount a drive from Linux on my macOS El Capitan laptop. I try a command like this:

```
sudo mount -o rw -t nfs nfs.subdomain.employer.com:/ifs/home/username /private/workspace/
cd /private/workspace/
echo "hello" > test.txt
-bash: test.txt: Permission denied
```

where `username` (the text, not the uid) is the same on my laptop as it is on the server (controlled by my employer). Unfortunately, while I can read files, I'm not getting write access. A colleague of mine said he tried that command from linux as my account and said it worked, but he doesn't know much about macs.

Comment: You have to set the permissions on the *remote* computer you have configured the nfs share on.  You need to edit the entry in the `/etc/exports` that pertains to your particular share.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to share directory over NFS from Mac? (w/o macOS Server app)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/282644/how-to-share-directory-over-nfs-from-mac-w-o-macos-server-app)

Comment: It looks like that link describes how to mount on Linux from macOS. I want the reverse. Also, as I understand it, my colleague was able to mount the drive on a Linux workstation, so the server is already set up. Does getting write access from macOS require different server settings or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: The last time I set up NFS sharing with macOS was a few years ago and from what I remember, there was some settings on the server that I had to configure for `rw` access.  Ever since I switched to SMB2, I don't have any of those issues anymore.

Answer (score 9):

I have this setup, please do the machine/folder names translation according to your case.
In /etc/exports on server side (mine is a centos 7):

```
/workspace_guest/02.code 
172.20.0.1(rw,sync,insecure,all_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)
```

From client side (macOS Catalina Version 10.15.6)

```
$ sudo mount -t nfs -o resvport,rw,noowners 172.20.0.100:/workspace_guest/02.code /Volumes/C76/02.code
```

There is a good explanation in [this post](https://serverfault.com/a/241272/407465) as "all_squash will map all UIDs and GIDs to the anonymous user, and anonuid and anongid set the UID and GID of the anonymous user.". I make it on the client side as "noowner" is to apply the current user/group as the "anonymous". You can also refer to [the other post](https://serverfault.com/a/1015162/407465) for the configuration.

Comment: Just used this solution today to mount Ubuntu 20.04 on MacOS Catalina and it worked perfectly.

Comment: "noowners" is what I tried to find for months. Thanks.